# Actionscript 3.0: Accessing Dynamic text from AS3 class to Game

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, colors, mouseevent

I have here a bubble popping game where bubbles fall from top of the game to the bottom and the player tries to pop as many bubbles as possible in 30 seconds. It is a 3 frame game, 1st frame is the start button, 2nd frame is the game, 3rd frame is the score and play again.
1st frame: Buttons to go to the second frame
2nd Frame: timer to count 30 seconds of play time
3rd frame: buttons to play again.

ScoreValue is a dynamic textbox in the last frame of the game. It records the points based on size the size scale of the bubble, and should be change based on the amount of bubbles the player has popped.

```
scoreValue.text = score.toString();
Error 1120: Access of unidentified property scoreValue
```

Anyways here the full package of the code.

```
    package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.media.Sound;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;

    public class Ball extends MovieClip{

        static public var burstCounter: uint;
        private var vx: Number;
        private var vy: Number;
        private var gravity: Number;
        private var stageWidth;
        private var stageHeight;
        private var bubble:Ball = new Ball();
        private var score: uint=0;

        public function Ball() {
            bubble.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize)
            bubble.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, burst)
            bubble.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropping)
        }

        public function initialize (e:Event):void
        {
            bubble.x = Math.random() * stageWidth;
            bubble.y = 0;

            stageWidth = stage.stageWidth;
            stageHeight = stage.stageHeight;

            bubble.vx = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            bubble.vy = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
            gravity = 0.1;

            var sizeScale = Math.random() * 1.2 + .6;
            bubble.scaleX = bubble.scaleY = sizeScale;
            score = (10 / sizeScale);
            scoreValue.text = score.toString();

            var colorTran = new ColorTransform();
            colorTran.color = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF;
            transform.colorTransform = colorTran;
            addChild(bubble);
        }
        function dropping(e: Event) :void
        {
            x += vx;
            y += vy;
            vy += gravity;

            if((x<0) || (x>stageWidth) || (y<0) || (y>stageHeight))
            {
                if(parent != null)
                {
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                }
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropping)
            }
        }
        function burst (e:Event):void
        {
            var ballonPopping: Sound = new BalloonPopping();
            bubble.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
            bubble.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, dropping);
            removeChild(bubble);

            ballonPopping.play();

            burstCounter += score;
        }

    }

}
```

Im getting this as output in my program, does any one know why?

```
Fonts should be embedded for any text that may be edited at runtime, other than text with the "Use Device Fonts" setting. Use the Text > Font Embedding command to embed fonts.
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thats usually just a warning that you have some dynamic textfield on your stage in which you selected a non-system font. What exactly is your problem? try to import MouseEvent (if thats your error) :import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Comment: **Error 1120: Access of unidentified property scoreValue** means that you are missing the textfield at some point.  Remember that an object you drag to the stage in the IDE has to be available on the stage by the time you call its methods - just having it on some keyframe later on will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in a class, functions should be defined as `public` or `private`. Second, your `burst` function is expecting an `Event` while you are assigning a `MouseEvent` to it. Its an easy mistake that I use to often do.

Change it to:

```
private function burst (e:MouseEvent):void
```

The font thing in the output panel means you have a dynamic text field somewhere. Simply go to your FLA, open up that textfield and on the properties panel, hit the embed button and choose the Basic Latin checkbox...or numerals if its just numbers

edit: Also change your import to

```
import flash.events.*;
```

or add

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```

Comment: FYI MouseEvent inherits Event. So with that being said as long as he is not trying to access any of the MouseEvent properties he can use Event as the parameter for the callback function burst.

Comment: Yup, you are right, but for best practices that is not the way to go.

Comment: @Ronnie It's not a mistake, and I'd like to see that best practice in writing.  Also, you can declare methods as `protected` or `internal`as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to import the MouseEvent class to fix the 'Access undefined property of MouseEvent'

add this to your import statements:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
```